# What to feed the datasource for a trirand.jqgrid grid with EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jqgrid

So far I have this but it doesnt work.  I was getting an existing datareader error but then i added the MARS property and set it to true and I got a new problem which was saying it was a null reference. I am not sure what to set the datasource as for it to fill the jqgrid on the view from the database which I am using EF with.  I have seen quite a few examples  but they werent that helpful for my situation.

```
public JsonResult BugJqGridDataRequested()
    {

        var bugGrid = new BugJqGridViewModel();
        var db = new BugContext();
        var bugs = db.Bugs.ToList();
        bugGrid.Grid.DataSource = bugs;
        return bugGrid.Grid.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BugJqGridDataRequested()
{
    using (var db = new BugContext()) {
        var bugs = db.Bugs.Select(b => new { Prop1 = b.Prop, Prop2 = b.NavigationProperty.Data }).ToList();
        return Json(new {
            /// The number of pages which should be displayed in the paging controls at the bottom of the grid.
            Total = 1,
            /// The current page number which should be highlighted in the paging controls at the bottom of the grid.
            Page = 1,
            /// Anything serializable
            /// UserData = null,

            //The number of all available bugs not just the number of the returned rows!
            Records = bugs.Count,
            Rows = bugs
        });
    }
}
```

Additional info: [Using jqGrid with ASP.NET MVC: LINQ Extensions](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/15/38212/)

Comment: im getting this error `The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.`

Then i removed the using then the error went away now im getting other errors to do with the JS files of the jqgrid... but your situation seems to be working

Comment: That is becouse the Bug entity has at least one navigation property and the json serializer tries to serialize that to but the DbContext has been disposed before serialization so we need to add a flattened type before building up the result set. I have edited my answer.